# How to prevent blocking http auth popups on firefox restart with many tabs open

Tags: browser-addons, http, web-development, firefox, authentication

I am using the latest firefox with tab mix plus and tabgoups manager. I have maybe 50 or 100 tabs oben in different tab groups. When I shutdown firefox and start it again all tabs and tab groups are perfectly rebuilt.

But I have also many pages open that are behind a standard http auth, and these pages all request their usernames and passwords. So during startup firefox pops up all these pages' http auth windows. And they block everything else in firefox, they are like modal windows. (I am involved in website development and the beta versions are behind apache http auth.)

I have to click many times the OK button in the popups, before I can do anything. All the usernames and passwords are already filled in. (And the firefox taskbar entry blinks and the firefox window heading also blinks, and focus switches back and foth, which also annoys me. And sometimes the popups do not react to my clicks, because firefox is maybe just switching focus somewhere else. This is the worst.)

I want a plugin or some way to skip those popups. There are some plugins I tried some time ago, but they did not do what I need, because they require a mouse click for each login, which is no improvement over the situation like it already is. This is not about password storage (because firefox already stores them). But of course, if some password storing plugin could heal this it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

AutoAuth - this should do what you want ... just installed it, works!

> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoauth/

(AutoAuth even works with Firefox 5, with [Nighly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/)'s *Force addon compatibility* setting.)

Answer (score 0):

[1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password) will solve this problem.  It is a pay app, and requires that you use it to handle all authentication (i.e., turn off saving passwords in Firefox).  This may be overkill for what you need, but it is a great app, and easily syncs passwords between computers.

Comment: it looks interesting but i am not using an apple computer so i cannot try it. thank you. maybe it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try lastpass https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8542 It's a free password manager that you can set to 'Auto logon' if desired.

Comment: Thank you Pulse. Looks very promising, will try this one soon...

Comment: I installed it. Do you know a way how I can make it work without registering to this company's site? I want my passwords only locally stored.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible with Lastpass. The only other option I can think of is Secure Login https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4429/

Comment: Thank you for secure Login. I have installed it and maybe I'll keep it, because it really does a good job. But this does not answer the question, because http authentication popups are not handled by this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I could do what I wanted with a newer version of the software `buzof` from `basta computing` , but this is not a really good solution, because it is not a firefox plugin, it works only on one platform (windows).

But it silently clicks "ok" on the popups.